# Is my Powerset function Running out of Memory?

Tags: c#, list, biginteger, powerset

I am using a powerset to find all of the possible sums of a set of BigIntegers (reference System.Numerics). First a helper class to sum the power set.

```
public static class Summer
{
     public static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, IAdder<T> adder)
     {
         T result = adder.Zero;
         foreach (var value in values)
         {
            result = adder.Add(result, value);
         }
         return result;
     }

     public interface IAdder<T>
     {
         T Zero { get; }

         T Add(T a, T b);
     }

     public class BigIntAdder : IAdder<BigInteger>
     {
         public static readonly BigIntAdder Instance = new BigIntAdder();

         public BigInteger Zero { get { return 0; } }

         public BigInteger Add(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) { return a + b; }
     }
 }
```

Then the function to get the power set.

```
     public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
     {
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                   where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                   select list[i];
     }
```

and call the powerset function

```
var result = GetPowerSet(numbers).Select(x => Summer.Sum<BigInteger>(x,new Summer.BigIntAdder())).ToList();
```

where numbers is an arbitrary List of numbers. I only get at most 65536 answers in my result List. Is it running out of memory? What part is running out of memory and how can I extend its memory?

I see it is 2^16 http://www.thecomputercoach.net/html/65536.html . I thought data types like List and IEnumerable went up to int.maxvalue (2^32). Why is this only going to 2^16 ? How can I extend this?

Comment: Are you sure that that's incorrect? How many items do you expect? Why? How would we know if it's correct if we don't know what `GetPowerSet` is.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Powerset should give 2^n answers back where n is numbers in set. If the numbers set contains 16 or less elements it will be correct, but if the numbers set contains more than 16 elements only some of the elements are returned. Powerset is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set